# Finding the equation of a curve using binormal vectors

Tags: differential-geometry

I just started taking Differential Geometry and I'm stuck on this question: "Mark off the line segments of fixed length on the binormals to a simple helix. Find the equation of a curve that is traced by the endpoints of these line segments."

I know how to find a binormal vector (i.e. $\beta= \frac{r' \times r''}{|r' \times r''|}$) but I basically have no clue how to do that with this question.

Comment: Hint: If the fixed lenght is $k$, then the final point can be $r(t)+\beta(t)k$, for each parameter $t$.